# prometheus plugin not found in rabbitmq 3.8.0

Tags: rabbitmq

We are running rabbitmq version 3.8.0 in openshift and trying to enable prometheus to monitor our rabbitmq cluster. As per the rabbitmq document, rabbitmq version 3.8.0 is shipped with prometheus plugin by default.

But, When we try to enable the prometheus plugin, we are getting plugin not found error like below.

```
I have no name!@rabbitmq-ss-0:/opt/rabbitmq$ rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_prometheus
rabbitmq_prometheus
Error:
{:plugins_not_found, [:prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter]}
```

```
I have no name!@rabbitmq-ss-0:/opt/rabbitmq$ rabbitmq-plugins directories
Plugin archives directory: /opt/rabbitmq/plugins
```

```
I have no name!@rabbitmq-ss-0:/opt/rabbitmq$ ls -l /opt/rabbitmq/plugins | grep prometheus
-rw-r--r--. 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq  219054 Oct  1 09:27 prometheus-4.4.0.ez
-rw-r--r--. 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   42180 Oct  1 09:27 rabbitmq_prometheus-3.8.0.ez
I have no name!@rabbitmq-ss-0:/opt/rabbitmq$
```

Please see the result of plugin list.

```
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache       3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_http        3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2      3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange       3.8.1
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.8.1
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws       3.8.1
[e*] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_common    3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_consul    3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_etcd      3.8.1
[E*] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s       3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_prometheus               3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_random_exchange          3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_recent_history_exchange  3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_sharding                 3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_top                      3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_trust_store              3.8.1
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt                 3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt_examples        3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.8.1
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.8.1
```

Comment: The output of `rabbitmq-plugins list` would be very helpful. Also, please note that version `3.8.1` is available and has important bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks @LukeBakken for your comments.
I installed rabbitmq 3.8.1 version and i am still getting the same error.
And, I edited my description with plugin list

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly shown:

```
Error:
{:plugins_not_found, [:prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter]
```

You must have enabled the `prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter` plugin at one point, and then removed the plugin file. You must find the `enabled_plugins` file and manually edit it to remove `prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter`. That file is usually located in `/var/lib/rabbitmq` or a subdirectory of that location.